# R Markdown - Create Dynamic Report Parameters

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on how to create dynamic parameters in a R Markdown Report.   Currently I have a report with eight parameters that are all hard coded.  I would like the values of these parameters to be dynamically derived (based off a query and therefore a data frame) and would like the value in an upper level parameter to drive the selection subset of a lower level parameter.

````
---
title: My Document
output: html_document
params:
  system:
    label: "Select System:"
    value: A
    input: select
    choices: [A, B]
  fig_num:
    label: "Starting Figure Number:"
    value: 1
    min: 1
    max: 100
    input: numeric
  attach_let:
    label: "Attachment Letter:"
    value: "A"
    input: text
  Program:
    label: "Select Program:"
    value: 1A 
    input: select
    choices: [1A, 1B, 2A, 2B]
  ProgramRisk:
    label: "Select Sample Program Risk:"
    value: 1
    input: select
    choices: [1, 2, 3]
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# set this option in the first code chunk in the document
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = params$printcode)
```
````

Ideally, I would like the values for System parameter to come directly from a SQL query (e.g - SELECT DISTINCT System from A.Table).  The user would then select a value and say in the Program parameter - these values were derived from another query (e.g. SELECT DISTINCT Program FROM B.Table where System = [Param$System].   This would thereby prevent the user inputting a value in the program that did not exist for that System.

I have seen that you can use !r to use R code directly in the YAML header, but this seems limited to basic calls (as.Date..., etc.).   Does anyone have any ideas how I could get this information to the parameters and allow the parameters to be filtered by another (earlier) parameter?

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can have normal R objects in a RMarkdown document; you only need to use `params` if you want to send data into the document from outside (for example if you're knitting from within an R script or Shiny app). You can run SQL queries in the code blocks of an RMarkdown object and use the results as a normal R object

Comment: Thanks @divibisan - I am trying to provide a front-end for more complicated report to allow users to have a more guided approach to getting the report they need.   In that way, I assumed the parameters would be necessary as the user selects the relevant items.   As the process is sequential, I assume that data exposed further on in the report is not available earlier (i.e. in the parameter section)?

Comment: It might help if you explained how you're going to use this in more detail. `.RMarkdown` documents are not meant for interactive use. Your best bet is either to do the SQL query in a separate R script or Shiny app and then pass the result to the `.rmd` in the  `params=` argument when rendering it, or just run the query in your `.rmd` and store the result as a normal R object.

Comment: `params` is just a R `list` object, so there's no reason that all your data needs to be in `params`

Comment: I was using the example from here:

Comment: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports#overview

Comment: The focus on using the parameter was to provide the end user with an interface to enter the information.  Once entered, this data is used in the publishing of a report.   The aim is to use this in much the same way you would work with an SSRS report.    In essence, for my purpose, all I need is a clean interface to prompt the report user to enter parameter details.   Beyond that I can process the report using whatever tools are best suited for the job.   The key requirement would be to allow the parameters to be filtered, as described above.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it looks like I can run true Shiny interactive elements in an HTML document that could act as an interface. I do appreciate that Shiny is at the core of RMarkdown, i guess I was being a bit single focused.  Although not as simple as the RMarkdown parameter, if offers much more flexibility as I can run code initially, allowing me to populate my parameters and control the filtering

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny

The workflow would then be:
1) Someone runs the Shiny code
2) Selects parameter values 
3) Click 'OK'
4) These values are used to render the underlying reports 
5) Reports are saved to as pdf.

@divibisan -  thanks for your help!  Got me thinking a bit differently.